# React doesn't show component in Laravel 5.8 blade

Tags: reactjs, laravel-5.8

I'm using a basic React installation on Laravel 5.8. My blade `hoolaMundo.blade.php` identifies the file `css/app.css` and `js/app.js`, but it doesn't show anything in the browser.

**holaMundo**

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="Example"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

**Component**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import Main from "../../assets/js/components/Example";
    
    class Example extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row justify-content-center">
                        <div className="col-md-8">
                            <div className="card">
                                <div className="card-header">Example Component</div>
    
                                <div className="card-body">I'm an example component!</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default Example;
    
    if (document.getElementById('Example')) {
        ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('Example'));
    }
```

**Web Result**

[image]

**extra information**

node -v :14.7.0
php -v : 7.3.5
npm -v: 4.14.7
**Done**
npm install
npm dev run

Comment: Is your HTML from the blade template there? Is the JS request from the server successful?

Comment: Is the JS request from the server successful? 
R: yes, this return a status 200
Is your HTML from the blade template there?
R: yeap is the holaMundo.blade.php, and I use the `<div id="Example"></div>` to print the information.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but have you tried putting the script tag inside the `html` tags? I don't know if that would make a difference as to what `document` is referring to but it might be worth a shot

Comment: @BrianThompson I did, but I got the same answer, the component don't show in the web.

Comment: Are you able to console log within the component? Like can you console log above the `if` to see what `document.getElementById('Example')` is returning?

Comment: @BrianThompson 
my console doesn't return anything. I use an exception `else` to print a message with the console.log but i don't have any type of answer .

Comment: So it seems your JS is not running

Answer (score 1):

I would usually use the comment section, due to my insufficent reputation I'll need to type a big answere.

1. thing, it would be greate to see your mix file? Did you use .react? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#react
2. Laravel does sometimes behave odd, no ofense I love it, but I would recommend using the asset function to refrence your styles scripts etc. Then you make sure everything is send out properly.
3. I would put the script tag within the html tag.
4. it would be great to know how you installed react? Did you use larvel or node way?
5. How I do it.
   I usually cd into my resource/js folder and install it via

   `npm i create-react-app myapp`

Then I go into laravel mix and paste in:

```
.react('resources/js/myapp/index.js', 'public/js/myapp.js');
```

If you cannot run `npm i create-react-app myapp` then yoou need to install it first. Checkout here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app